# Raspberry Pi 3B+ not booting and no green light

Tags: boot, boot-issues

My Raspberry Pi worked for more than a year and someday, when I try rebooting it, my Raspberry Pi was stuck with the red light but no green light and nothing on the screen plugged with HDMI. Since this time, I tried different images and different SD card, but it still doesn't boot.

UPDATE: The 3V3 doesn't work

Comment: Please follow the [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151) and tell us, what step fails.

Comment: It fails at the step where the 3V3 doesn't work. Does that mean that my Raspberry Pi is broken and I have to buy another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I just bought a new Raspberry Pi.